# Running a mapsforge map app

Tags: android, maps, offline-caching

I am trying to create a mapsforge offline maps app. I followed the guidelines or there website 
below is the snapshot of my code
[image]

But when i run this app , the app crashes. The logcat is as following.
[image]

[image]

However if i comment out the  in mainfest. the app works fine. I am unable to figure out the problem. Kindly help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stacktrace suggests that you are having an issue writing to the SD card. Do you have the following permission in your manifest file?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thankyou. Actually i am new to android development. So don't know how to track the errors.